# How to use Powerpoint VBA to manipulate embeded excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint deck with 100 charts. Each chart contains an embedded Excel file. Opening each embedded Excel file and get data from elsewhere to paste into it would take forever. Hence, I am trying to automate this process.(It definitely has some economic value, considering all the research and consulting firms doing this manually everyday.)

1. Using PowerPoint VBA, my code below is able to copy a range data from an external Excel file and paste into the embedded excel file in PowerPoint. However, I cannot control where to paste it and it is now happening randomly; I want the pasted range to start from range("A1").

[image: screenshot]

-

```
Sub UpdateChartData3()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = shp.Chart
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet 
    'This clear all the data in the embedded excel file for the chart(1)
    '    in the first slide.
    Set wb = cht.ChartData.Workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Cells.Clear
    Dim Databook As Excel.Application
    Set Databook = New Excel.Application
    Databook.Visible = True 
    'This opens up an external excel file. Copy a range from the Excel
    '    file and paste into the embedded excel file
    Databook.Workbooks.Open "C:\Folder\Master Slide.xlsx", True, False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Copy
    wb.Activate
    Ws.Paste
    Set Databook = Nothing
```

2. The real problem is that when you turn on the Microsoft Excel Object Library from powerpoint. Excel and Powerpoint only talk to each other at a minimal level; this happens when using Excel VBA as well. My research shows that to reach to the embedded workbook for the chart in powerpoint, the object-oriented programming flow should be:

`PowerPoint.presentations.slides.shapes.chart.chartdata.workbook.worksheet.range`

Hence, logically if I change the code `Ws.paste` (from the above coding) into something below, it should work but It did not.

```
ws.Range("A1").selection
Selection.paste
'This is to expand the source data table of the chart, so that the chart
'    in Powerpoint can be automated.
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
ws.ListObjects("Table1").Resize ws.rng
```

The real issue is the lack of PowerPoint VBA documentation. Could someone help on this?

Comment: You should use code tags (I am editing this post this time) instead of quotes ([ask]). Also, some additional examples/information to expand on "it should work but it did not" areas - how do you know it is not working and what debugging have you tried to narrow it down. Microsoft has plenty of VBA reference material on-line so you should also be able to use these resources to get some answers.

Comment: Hi AJD, thanks for the advice. I am posting my question the first time. I have been googling for a long time and I could not think there  is a right VBA reference material for my question online.

Comment: If I was tyring to tackle this problem (and I have tried to tackle similar problems in the past), I would be looking to simplify how data is transferred between the source (in this case Excel files) and the presentation. Perhaps link from PowerPoint directly to charts in the Excel files? I know this type of automation can be complex, best bet is to solve one little part at a time, then step back and refactor! While the VBA documents would not cover your entire problem, it should help with each little step and this would give you more ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will keep pushing nevertheless. haha

Comment: @JerryChen -  re:"`The real issue is the lack of PowerPoint VBA documentation`".  There is as much official documentation as there is for using VBA with any other Office product, but what you may be noticing is that there isn't as many examples on forums like [so] because *not very many people have a needs to use VBA with PowerPoint*.  That being said, [Google "Office VBA Interop"](http://google.ca/search?q=vba+office+interop) to learn more about controlling an Office app with another.  For example: **[Excel Object Model Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx)**

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I faced - not much documentation. It should actually be an easy task logically but syntax wise, I have to trial and error. It is great to know that someone has worked on this before. I will jump into office vba interop to take a look. :)